# How is the toilet tank itself refilled?

Tags: plumbing, toilet

We learned here:

- [Purpose of Fill Valve Tube Going into Overflow Drain](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/44534/purpose-of-fill-valve-tube-going-into-overflow-drain)

...that the fill valve sends water directly into the overflow drain...and that ***fills the bowl***.

However, how does ***the tank*** (directly or indirectly) get filled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that particular type of fill valve, the water comes out of the two areas highlighted in yellow in the picture:

1. The fill tube clipped to the overflow tube.
2. The bottom of the vertical tube that the fill valve sits on.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

By the valve operated by the float.

As the water rises in the tank the float floats and at a certain height that closes the valve which stops filling the tank as it is ready for the next flush.